# How can I change this to not allow a negative number in the final count?

Tags: python

I'm having an issue with this assignment. It's something where the last week won't adjust the final interest/principal payment so that the balance can't go below zero. I thought that making my code `while startBalance > 0` would stop it would allowing that?

```
price = float(input("Enter the purchase price: "))
down = .10
apr = .12
monthlyRate = .05
month = 0
downPayment = price * down 
startBalance = price - downPayment
payment = startBalance * monthlyRate

print("%s%19s%18s%19s%10s%17s" % ("Month", "Starting Balance", "Interest to Pay", "Principal to Pay", "Payment", "Ending Balance"))

while startBalance > 0:
    month += 1
    interest = startBalance * apr / 12
    principal = payment - interest
    endBalance = startBalance - principal


    print("%2d%16.2f%16.2f%18.2f%18.2f%15.2f" % (month, startBalance, interest, principal, payment, endBalance))

    startBalance = endBalance
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you could technically have `startBalance > 0` but when you calculate `principal`, `principal > startBalance`

One way to handle this is by adjusting the payment to be the minimum of the normal calculated amount and the remainingBalance

```
payment = startBalance * monthlyRate

print("%s%19s%18s%19s%10s%17s" % ("Month", "Starting Balance", "Interest to Pay", 
"Principal to Pay", "Payment", "Ending Balance"))

while startBalance > 0:
    month += 1
    interest = startBalance * apr / 12
    principal = min(payment - interest, remainingBalance)
    endBalance = startBalance - principal

    print("%2d%16.2f%16.2f%18.2f%18.2f%15.2f" % (month, startBalance, interest, principal, payment, endBalance))

    startBalance = endBalance
```

Comment: So it made the last day not be able to below $0 but the math now doesn't add up. The software for the assignment wants there to be no interest payment and a payment of $3.80 for week 23. Below is the result I got from messing around with the code from your suggestion.

22           12.68            0.13              8.87              9.00           3.80
23            3.80            0.04              3.80              9.00           0.00

Comment: Ah sorry, I did not notice the print statement. I see now why you have start and end balances. I have edited my answer